# Receiving tcp message using Android

Tags: android, tcp

I am developing a remote control app to control all my devices (TV, media centre etc) I originally wrote it to use the remote Sony API which worked quite well but now I want to try and control the devices over my network.

I have completed the TV which uses SOAP requests and now I am doing my media center which is a PC.
My problem is that I can send a command which the media centre responds to correctly (I can see the response coming back using Wireshark). The commands being sent are in variables str and str1.

I am quite new to programming Android and have little knowledge on IP, so I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am using API 19 (I am the only one to be using the app), at the moment it will crash just after sending my TCP command. I suspect I am doing something stupid. My code is as follows:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
String success;
Button btnok;
TextView txtvwdata1;

MyTask objMyTask;

private Socket socket;
public Void result;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 8017;
private static final String URL = "192.168.1.95";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
    txtvwdata1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvwdata1);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            objMyTask = new MyTask();
            objMyTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(URL);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String str = "\r\n{\"Type\":\"identify\",\"AppName\":null,\"Authenticate\":{\"AuthMethod\":\"userpass\",\"Password\":\"admin\",\"User\":\"admin\"},\"Description\":\"Android client for MediaPortal\",\"Name\":\"Steve\",\"Version\":\"1.0\"}\r\n";
            String str1 = "\r\n{\"Type\":\"playchannel\",\"ChannelId\":1315,\"StartFullscreen\":true}\r\n";

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
            delay();
            out.println(str1);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Get Response    
        InputStream is = null;
        // is= connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
        try {
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            rd.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("response", "" + response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String onPostExecute()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public void delay()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100000)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If apps crash you will get detailed info in the logcat. Please post a relevant part of it here in an extra block. Looking at your code you should not continue if there was a catch but end the method/function.

Comment: `private Socket socket;`. Change to `private Socket socket=null;`. In onClick check if socket==null. And if it is null then display a Toast saying so and do not start the AsyncTask. Where are you running this? Emulator/phone/device? So it connects? Only when the user presses the button you have a crash?

Comment: `response.append('\r');`. Change to `response.append("\n");`

Comment: `InputStream is = null;`. A null stream will not work so initiate with `is = socket.getInputStream();`

Comment: `delay();`. If you need a delay then your server code or your protocol is no good.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response, logcat indicates doInBackground(). if I remove everything about the InputStream it works fine which confirms the error in logcat. I can't understand the rest of logcat myself.

Comment: Thats why i asked you to post a part of the logcat here. Did you apply my suggestions? Do!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your help greenapps, that has solved my problem. After making the changes you suggested now no crash and getting the response.

```
private Socket socket=null;
is = socket.getInputStream(); 
response.append("\n");
```

This is the code I have now:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


String success;
Button btnok;
TextView txtvwdata1;

MyTask objMyTask;

public String result;

private Socket socket=null;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 8017;
private static final String URL = "192.168.1.95";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
    txtvwdata1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvwdata1);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            objMyTask = new MyTask();
            objMyTask.execute();
            txtvwdata1.setText(result);
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(URL);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String str = "\r\n{\"Type\":\"identify\",\"AppName\":null,\"Authenticate\":{\"AuthMethod\":\"userpass\",\"Password\":\"admin\",\"User\":\"admin\"},\"Description\":\"Android client for MediaPortal\",\"Name\":\"aMPdroid\",\"Version\":\"1.1.3\"}\r\n";
            String str1 = "\r\n{\"Type\":\"playchannel\",\"ChannelId\":1315,\"StartFullscreen\":true}\r\n";

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
            out.println(str1);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Get Response    
        try
        {
            InputStream is= socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                int a = 1;
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append("\r\n");
                    Log.i("response", "" + response.toString());
                    if (a == 1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    a++;
                }
                result = response.toString();
                return response.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                rd.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String onPostExecute()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do not post an answer yourself in this way. Leave answers to others if you did not find the answer yourself. You could have told in a comment that my suggestions worked.

Comment: I won't exactly agree with greenaps there - a poster is free to state what worked especially if all they have been given so far are hints.  But that's beside the point as this isn't a workable answer anyway - the code posted here will obviously crash with a null pointer exception when it attempts to invoke the getInputStream() on the just-nullified socket.

Comment: Sorry about that, as mentioned when I completed the answer, greenapps suggestions did solve my problem. It did not work as it should as the server continued to send data so was stuck in the while loop, that I can solve once I understand how the remote plugin on mediaportal works but otherwise I am now receiving data which I can now process. Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, please read complete post and realise that OP did not post a piece of -working- code but merery summed up the individual statements which i suggested to change or add.

Comment: This is now the code I have which is only being used for testing purposes at the moment:-

Comment: `After making the changes you suggested`. Except for checking socket==null in onClick. It will catch you one day if you dont!!!!

Comment: `txtvwdata1.setText(result);`. That is the wrong place as the async task is not yet finished. You should put that statement in onPostExecte() instead. Your onPostExecute will not be called now as its declaration is not ok.